# How to apply conditional statement in numpy array?

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to apply conditional statements in a numpy array and to get a boolean array with 1 and 0 values.

I tried so far the np.where(), but it allows only 3 arguments and in my case I have some more.

I first create the array randomly:

```
numbers = np.random.uniform(1,100,5)
```

Now, if the value is lower then 30, I would like to get a 0. If the value is greater than 70, I would like to get 1. And if the value is between 30 and 70, I would like to get a random number between 0 and 1. If this number is greater than 0.5, then the value from the array should get 1 as a boolean value and in other case 0. I guess this is made again with the np.random function, but I dont know how to apply all of the arguments.

If the input array is:

```
[10,40,50,60,90]
```

Then the expected output should be:

```
[0,1,0,1,1]
```

where the three values in the middle are randomly distributed so they can differ when making multiple tests.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) and 3rd condition should should be simplify by [`numpy.random.choice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html):

```
numbers = np.array([10,40,50,60,90])
print (numbers)
[10 40 50 60 90]

a = np.select([numbers < 30, numbers > 70], [0, 1], np.random.choice([1,0], size=len(numbers)))
print (a)
[0 0 1 0 1]
```

If need `3rd` condition with compare by `0.5` is possible convert mask to integers for `True, False` to `1, 0` mapping:

```
b = (np.random.rand(len(numbers)) > .5).astype(int)
#alternative
#b = np.where(np.random.rand(len(numbers)) > .5, 1, 0)

a = np.select([numbers < 30, numbers > 70], [0, 1], b)
```

Or you can chain 3 times [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
a = np.where(numbers < 30, 0,
    np.where(numbers > 70, 1, 
    np.where(np.random.rand(len(numbers)) > .5, 1, 0)))
```

Or use `np.select`:

```
a = np.select([numbers < 30, numbers > 70, np.random.rand(len(numbers)) > .5], 
               [0, 1, 1], 0)
```

Comment: Thanks you! I have never used the np.select so far. Will take a closer look to this function :)

Comment: Well, and for numbers between 30 and 70, we use the np.random function. So far, so good. But then if they get a value lower or equal than 0.5, the boolean value should be 0. If they get a value greater than 0.5, then they obtain the value 1.